SwiftUI: Keyboard toolbar not appearing when TextField is not on rootview
On iOS, my app's root view has a NavigationStack, and when I push another view onto it that has a TextField, it will not display a toolbar over it when focused. But if I put the same TextField on the root view, it will work just fine. Does anyone know why this is happening? I noticed that it works fine on the iOS 18 simulator, but I'm having the problem when I run it on my device (iPhone 12 Pro running iOS 18.2).
struct HomeView: View
{
    @State private var navigationDestinationIsPresented = false
    
    var body: some View
    {
        NavigationStack
        {
            Button("Push Me")
            {
                self.navigationDestinationIsPresented = true
            }
            .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
            .navigationDestination(isPresented: self.$navigationDestinationIsPresented)
            {
                NextView()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct NextView: View
{        
    var body: some View
    {
        NumTextField()
    }
 }

struct NumTextField: View
{
    @State private var userInput: String = ""
    @FocusState var isFocused: Bool
    
    var body: some View
    {
        TextField("", text: self.$userInput)
        .border(Color.black, width: 1.0)
        .frame(width: 45)
        .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
        #if os(iOS)
        .keyboardType(.numberPad)
        .toolbar
        {
            if (self.isFocused)
            {
                ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .keyboard)
                {
                    Spacer()
                    
                    Button("Done")
                    {
                        self.isFocused = false
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        #endif
        .focused(self.$isFocused)
    }
}


I cannot reproduce on iOS 18.1 simulator.

@Sweeper I just ran it on iOS18 simulator and notice it works there as well. where I'm having my issue though is on the device (iPhone12 Pro running iOS 18.2).
